# xrandr -- how to find the correct RGB full spectrum output command for my system

Tags: 16.04, display, hdmi, amd-graphics, xrandr

I have just hooked up my laptop to an external monitor after a "spillage incident" foobared the built-in display. However, when I connect the monitor via an HDMI cable the colours look extremely washed out. I searched around a bit and found this is probably due to the laptop graphics card not outputting the full RGB spectrum via HDMI by default. I found a solution here:

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63895-Black-level-too-high-after-upgrade-to-13-10

recommending this command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

which doesn't work on my system, since the parameters are not applicable:

```
output HDMI1 not found; ignoring X Error of failed request: 
BadRROutput (invalid Output parameter)   Major opcode of failed     
request:  140 (RANDR)   Minor opcode of failed request:  15 
(RRGetOutputProperty)   Serial number of failed request:  28   Current 
serial number in output stream:  28
```

I ran:

```
xrandr -q
```

and the output:

```
[...]
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

provided me with the correct `--output` parameter, `HDMI-0`. However, I am unsure how to find a list of parameters and values applicable on my system when using the `--set` flag, so I can work out what to use in place of "Broadcast RGB" "Full". At the moment the command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

outputs:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

I also ran `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0d00000-f0d3ffff memory:f0d80000-f0d9ffff
```

But could not find anything which seemed immediately useful in the resulting information.

I also ran `xrandr --verbose` which outputs:

```
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x60) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
    Identifier: 0x52
    Timestamp:  36995480
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004c2d860400000000
        06130103801009780aee91a3544c9926
        0f5054bfef80714f81408180a9408100
        b30095000101023a801871382d40582c
        4500a05a0000001e011d00bc52d01e20
        b8285540a05a0000001e000000fd0018
        4b1a5117000a202020202020000000fc
        0053796e634d61737465720a202001a5
        020323f14b930405140312101f202122
        2309070783010000e2000f67030c0010
        00b82d011d80d0721c1620102c2580a0
        5a0000009e011d8018711c1620582c25
        00a05a0000009e011d007251d01e206e
        285500a05a0000001e8c0ad090204031
        200c405500a05a000000180000000000
        0000000000000000000000000000007a
    output_csc: bypass 
        supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
    audio: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    dither: off 
        supported: off, on
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x60) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x61) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x62) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080i (0x63) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x64) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x65) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  30.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x66) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  25.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x67) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  27.00KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  24.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x68) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080 (0x69) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  29.97Hz
  1920x1080 (0x6a) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2558 end 2602 total 2750 skew    0 clock  26.97KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  23.98Hz
  1600x1200 (0x6b) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x6c) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x1024 (0x6d) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x6e) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x6f) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x960 (0x70) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x800 (0x71) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x72) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x73) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x74) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x75) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x76) 78.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.08Hz
  1024x768 (0x77) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x78) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x79) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x7a) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x7b) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x7c) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x7d) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  720x576 (0x7e) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x7f) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x80) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x81) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x82) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  491 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x83) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x84) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x85) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x86) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x53
    Timestamp:  36995480
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    output_csc: bypass 
        supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    load detection: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
```

For the relevant monitor/connection.

If this were not possible with `xrandr` I would also be willing to accept any answer telling me how to retrieve data from and manipulate output of RandR/X11 via a different method.

Answer (score 6):

You just missed a dash "-"  between `HDMI` and `1`. The corrected command is:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Broadcast RGB` property is for Intel graphics cards. `output_csc` appears to be the AMD variant of the same thing.

`output_csc` is set to `bypass` in what you posted, which should be equivalent to the `Full` range (0-255).

You can try setting `output_csc` to other valid options, notably `tvrgb` (16-235).

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set "output_csc" "bypass"
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set "output_csc" "tvrgb"
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set "output_csc" "ycbcr601"
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set "output_csc" "ycbcr709"
```

It's also possible that some of your monitor's settings need fiddling with.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sudo kernelstub -a amdgpu.dc=0
reboot
```

Comment: Could you expand on what this actually does? A more complete answer may help more people in the future 

Comment: This seems related to https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/476